# will_paginate destroys saved ids while changing the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate in order to list huge number of files. I also have a check_box in order to choose files for the futher analysis.
To save the ids in the cookie while changing the pages I used following javascript:

```
 <script src="/assets/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
var checkedIds = []

$('.checkmeplease').on("change", function(){ 

   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       checkedIds.push($(this).val())

   }
    else  {
       checkedIds.splice(checkedIds.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);

   }
    $.cookie('checked_file_ids', checkedIds,{path:'/'});
 });


 </script>
```

My checkboxes:

```
 <% @files.each do |file| %>   
 <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id,false,:class=>'checkmeplease'  %></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= file.name %></p> 
 <%end%>
```

It saves the IDs but when I change the page with will_pagination, the saved IDs disappear.

I was introduced as well this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkedIds = $.cookie('checked_file_ids');
$('p td input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       checkedIds.push($(this).val())
   }
    else  {
       checkedIds.splice(checkedIds.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
   }
    $.cookie('checked_file_ids', checkedIds);
})

 </script>
```

But  `$('p td input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function ()` does not seem to work.

Where is my mistake? How can I save the IDs from the previous pages as well?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use your first example, but instead of this line:

```
var checkedIds = []
```

Use this line from your second example.

```
var checkedIds = $.cookie('checked_file_ids');
```

The problem I see with the first example is that you never load the previously saved ids from the cookie.  So, come page two, when you check some, you're overwriting the previous values.

Comment: Yep, I do not load it, becauseI am not sure how to detect if the page was switched, so that I could before load the previously save ids. And I do not know how to disinguisch the pages then as well

Comment: If I use var checkedIds = $.cookie('checked_file_ids'); it gives me an error, that checkedIds is not defined